# Splitting up Yesod's Foundation.hs into different modules

Tags: haskell, yesod

Starting out with the scaffolded Yesod app, Foundation.hs has quite a lot going on.  As my app has grown, I have been trying to split some functionality out into different modules.  For example, the `defaultLayout` definition, and the related definition of `MenuItem` types, looks like something that would be better off moved to a separate module.  However, my attempts to do so have been thwarted.

To define menu items as part of the `defaultLayout` requires importing Foundation to get the route data constructors (ie `StaticR`, `AuthR` and my own routes defined in `config/routes`), and importing Application to get the Yesod instances for the `App` type.  But Foundation would need to import this module to define `defaultLayout`!

Is it possible to move this stuff into a separate module?  How do people avoid massive monolithic Foundations?